# ButterKnige биндинг объекта

Tags: android, binding, butterknife

Собственно вся суть вопроса - решил начать применять ButterKnife, уж очень интересно он экономит строки кода (ну и время при применении плагина).
И все бы хорошо - да есть одна непонятка, можно сразу в список выбрать несколько элементов:

```
@BindViews({ R.id.first_name, R.id.middle_name, R.id.last_name })
List<EditText> nameViews;
```

и есть объект - допустим `User`, поля которого и есть данные для вывода в эти элементы, но не могу понять - неужто каждый элемент необходимо прописывать обновление, или я не нашел биндинга объекта в список?

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. Что именно вы хотите реализовать синтаксически? Что-то типа `nameViews.setValues(arrayWithThreeStringsInIt)`? Если да - то это невозможно. Надо циклом бежать по вьюхам и им значения задавать. Не думаю, что в вашем случае вам это нужно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, именно одной строкой заполнить данными из объекта все поля на вьюхе - сделал через `Binding Data`